# Native C++ HTTPS REST call with certificate validation

Tags: c++, linux, rest, ssl, https

What library is the best to use for the purpose? Target platform is Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picked up [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) thus it is enforced with SSL certificate validation. Regarding to REST, I am able to send GET and POST requests also. However it is C but not C++ library. But it does not make a big difference for me because the syntax is pretty clear and there are lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell the best, but i used Qt (QNetworkAccessManager) and a Qt JSON Parser with success.